# Is ArcGIS Online unable to change the comma separator from comma to point?

Tags: arcgis-online

I am building an ArcGIS-Online Dashboard for a German partner. I have installed indicators which has a hosted feature as it's data source. When showing the values, the decimal separator is a point which is wrong. In Germany, the comma separator is used as a decimal point, and the point is used as a thousand separator.

I can see no way of changing it. Is this problem solvable?

Comment: Are you asking if standard Comma Separated Value (CSV) files can be generated without commas? Probably not. But you could easily write or adapt a filter to rewrite records from CSV to present them as required.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Check the documentation on the widget to see how to control presentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of ArcGIS Operations Dashboard, with a German operating system and German regional settings set, so that the point is the 1000 separator and the comma is for decimal places do not display correctly within Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS.

The Windows version(windows 7 German OS) of Operations Dashboard (i.e. operation views) is in Mature support status. And as far I have worked with Ops Dashboards No new development, bug fixes, or patches will be done by Esri for this particular issue.